# C# - ASP.NET Routes Handling in IIS7

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, url-routing, iis-7.5

I have a web application working fine in IIS6. Its using routes using System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection.

When I try to run it under IIS7.5 with Framework 4, first It gave me errors on scriptResourceHandler section of web.config.

After removing it, its opening in IIS7 .. but routes are not working and it gives 404 error.

How to fix this?

Comment: 404 error comes now, it seems like its not recognizing routes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** .. It was fixed after installing URL Rewrite module provided by Microsoft on server.